# Создание PDF с помощью PHP - знаки вопроса (???????) вместо кириллицы

Tags: php, pdf

Скачал скрипт, который формирует PDF файл и отправляет его на почту.
Но PDF не поддерживает кириллицу, там просто знаки вопроса.
В самом письме с кириллицей проблем нет.
Вы можете попробовать сами: https://fridger.com.ua/amigo/sender.php

Все php файлы сохранил в UTF-8 без ВОМ, вначале каждого уже впихнул

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Если посмотреть свойства PDF файла, то там видно что проблема то ли с кодировкой, то ли со шрифтом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать - не знаю.
Может подскажет кто?
PHP файлы прикреплять не стал, там они огромные, и их штук 10.
Поиск по файлам "Ansi" и "ArialMT" ничего не дал.

Comment: Сейчас прилетят инопланетяне, телепатически узнают, через что Вы компилите PDF и сразу поймут, где теряется кириллица. А если серьезно, то [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - вам сюда.

Comment: У вас **двоичный** файл, какой UTF-8 ? Кодировка применяется для текстовых файлов. Для pdf хедер  `Content-type: application/pdf` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2 Но проблема скорее всего другая, либо ваша библиотека не поддерживает кирилицу, либо вы не правильно вызываете функцию для создания pdf.

Comment: @nick_n_a - вот прямо написали, что я хотел сказать! Знак нужен - "терапевт-телепат" :-)

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно через какую библиотеку вы формируете пдф, но хочу посоветовать TCPDF - мощная и в то же время простая библиотека для формирования пдф. На днях на ней остановился. Проблем с кириллицей не возникло.

Comment: Через TCPDF, но я понял что разобраться пока что не смогу.
Нашел на JS скрипт, который генерит PDF, но правда на стороне клиента. То есть сохранить на сервер, и потом отправить на мейл нельзя (т.е можно но средствами ангуляр, чем я не владею).
https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/

Comment: бегите от pdfmake! На своем примере столкнулся, ужаснулся и перешел на mPdf. Удобно и просто